# Compute $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x+1} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Compute $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x+1} \, dx$$ in terms of $A$ given that $$A = \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(x)}{(x+2)^2} \, dx$$

I tried integration by parts with no avail. Please $\textbf{only provide hints}$, I still want to work on this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate the integral using another integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737101/calculate-the-integral-using-another-integral) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cdfrac%7B%5Csin(x)%5Ccos(x)%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D%20dx%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ and substitute $y=2x$.

Comment: Okay let me try that. I'll be surprised if this worked since I didn't go this route since I couldn't see how the denominator can change from $(x+1)$ to $(x+2)$

Comment: Ahhhhh! I should have tried that. I see now!

Comment: I actively avoided the correct route because of the denominator. This is a good lesson that I should stop being presumptuous

Comment: Is the answer: $\frac{1}{2(\pi+2)} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{A}{2}$ ? Edit: yes it is according to the answer in the question link that this question is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{\sin x\cos x}{x+1}dx
&= -\frac14\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{d(\cos 2x)}{x+1}\\
\end{align}